# Converting Angular ng-model to integer when writing to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using AngularFire for taking inputs and saving them to my Firebase database. Currently, I have an input for entering the price of a service, like so (I am using an input type of "text" instead of "number", since I don't want it to cause problems in older browsers):

```
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your monthly price here" ng-model="priceMonthly" required/></p>
```

However, when I write this to my Firebase upon form submission (using the update function), it writes the value `$scope.priceMonthly` as a string instead of an integer. What's the best way to write this value as an integer instead of a string?

Answer (score 11):

What about `type="number"`, like:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myText" name="inputName">
```

Since you want to make to user write numbers only. The `$scope.myText` should be the number in this case.

*as a side note:*

to be sure that you sent integer, print the value on the screen like:

```
<pre>myText as number: {{priceMonthly|json}}</pre>
```

if the value is wrapped with quotes - its a string, none - number.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but I am trying to do the same thing with an <option>'s value attribute from a <select> element instead of a plain old <input>. Any idea's for the select?

Comment: what if the input type is **hidden**?

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to integer:

```
var priceMonthly = parseInt($scope.priceMonthly, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

For any input type other than "number" (text, range, etc), you could add a [$parser](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) to your input, which will cast it's value for you:

```js
angular.module('exampleApp', [])

.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.filter = {
        number: 10
    };
})

.directive('castToInteger', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                return parseInt(value, 10);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" ng-model="filter.number" cast-to-integer="true" />
      <p>{{filter | json}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187142/818862