# How to update model value on user input via Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I am trying to build an app for calculating tax using angular.js as a tutotrial for me to understand the framework. First thing I noticed is that user input is by default assumed to be string, which obviously makes sum function a string concatenation instead of numerical operation, see here:

```
var taxApp = angular.module('taxApp', []);

taxApp.controller('taxController', function($scope) {

    $scope.user_data = {
      income_1: 0.00,
      income_2: 0.00
    };

    $scope.total = function() {
      return $scope.user_data.income_1 + $scope.user_data.income_2;
    };


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96beZ/3/

I could add parseFloat for each attribute but the thing is my app will eventually have about 10-20 user input fields and between 5-10 calculations. I want to avoid having multiple repetitions of parseFLoat all over the place in controller code. So far, I only got something like that using ng-change:

```
...
$scope.parseFLoat = function(model) {
  $scope.user_data[model] = parseFloat($scope.user_data[model]);
};
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96beZ/5/

The thing I don't like though is that I still need to pass the variable name so this is too model name dependent.

Is there a smarter way to achieve what I want, perhaps using directives? Or maybe Angular has an in-built function for changing value types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input type to **number**

```
<label for="income-1">Income 1</label>
<input type="number" id="income-1" ng-model="user_data.income_1" />
<label for="income-2">Income 2</label>
<input type="number" id="income-2" ng-model="user_data.income_2" />
```

and it will convert to numbers automatically.

In a more complex situation (for example you need input type to be **text** for some reason), you can easily build directives to take care of the conversion, see e.g. [Input model changes from Integer to String when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072152/angularjs-input-model-changes-from-integer-to-string-when-changed)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about this field type, I guess I am still reluctant to use HTML5 new elements. The code with directive is what I was looking for too, will definitely use that for some type conversions.