# How to assign value based on property in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, prototype, ngresource

I store leads statutes in my database. The values could be 1,2,3 or 4.

Actually I return a human readable using the ngResource get:

```
Client.get({ id: $stateParams.clientId }, function(data) {
    $scope.client = data;

    // Start of numeric values to status
    for(var i=0;i<data.leads.length;i++){
        if(data.leads[i].statut===1){
            data.leads[i].statutMessage = 'À contacter';
        }
        else if(data.leads[i].statut===2){
            data.leads[i].statutMessage = 'En cours';
        }
        else if(data.leads[i].statut===3){
            data.leads[i].statutMessage = 'Obtenu';
        }
        else if(data.leads[i].statut===4){
            data.leads[i].statutMessage = 'Non obtenu';
        }
    }

});
```

I would like **to extract this logic** to Client service so that each leads "statut" (1,2,3,4) is converted to real statutes ('À contacter', 'En cours', 'Obtenu', 'Non obtenu').

Can I use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072152/angularjs-input-model-changes-from-integer-to-string-when-changed) (directive)

If a directive is not the right way in this case, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when you need to display the "statutes" you could modelize it this way in your controller:

```
$scope.leadMessages = {
  1: 'À contacter',
  2: 'En cours',
  3: ..etc
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="lead in data.leads">{{leadMessages[lead.statut]}}</div>
```

Bon courage :-)

Comment: Thank you/ Merci! Je vais utiliser cette technique.