# parseInt return value from radio button AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now...

I've got a set of radio buttons to rate something between 1 and 5 with each set to value = 1, value = 2 and so on as part of a comment form.  But when the data is returned to the controller and is pushed to the db.json file, the radio button values are of type string.  How do I get them to be of type int?

Radio button HTML code:

```
<label class = "radio-inline" for = "one"><input type = "radio"
name = "rating" id = "one" data-ng-model = "userComment.rating" 
value = 1 required>1</label>
```

code from controllers.js:

```
$scope.submitComment = function() {
  $scope.movie.comments.push($scope.userComment);
  myFactory.getMovies().update({id:$scope.movie.id}, $scope.movie);
```

I tried this thinking it would work, but it didn't.

```
$scope.userComment.rating = parseInt($scope.userComment.rating);
```

Comment: `parseInt($scope.userComment.rating);` this should work as expected, where it is showing as string. just `console.log($scope.userComment.rating)` after `pasrseInt`.

Comment: @Sravan , I thought so too.  But here is the console.log results:   author
:
"My Name"
comment
:
"Pretty good movie"
date
:
"2017-01-20T04:48:00.551Z"
rating
:
"4"      ......    this is where it should be an int, but is still a string

Comment: where you are checking the console?, even if it is storing in the string format, you can always change back to number. Pls paste the code where you `console.log()` it.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot!  LOL But hey, we all make mistakes, right?  The parseInt() worked as it should have...I was calling up an old file and the parseInt() was not even being used!  Sorry for asking this question before exploring all options of my errors.  Hopefully, this will help others someway anyhow.  Cheers!

Comment: Oh, humans make mistakes, np, have a good day :)

Comment: since you have given a number in radio value, there may not be a need for `parseInt` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input model changes from Integer to String when changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072152/input-model-changes-from-integer-to-string-when-changed)

Answer (score 5):

Simply try to use [**ng-value**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/directive/ngValue) instead of **value** attribute:

```
<label class = "radio-inline" for = "one"><input type = "radio"
name = "rating" id = "one" data-ng-model = "userComment.rating" 
ng-value = "1" required>1</label>
```

Comment: Yes. To those who are interested, the "value" attribute should be used when you want to return a string, while the "ng-value" atribute should used when you want to return anything else (boolean, integer, array, etc.) See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D#!

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Like you have said, using parseInt(string) will give you an integer.
2. Since, that did not work, We can use the Number class of javascript to convert string to type number. You can do it like so :

   $scope.userComment.rating = Number($scope.userComment.rating);