# angular resource save sometimes converts int to string

Tags: angularjs

In the controller,

```
$scope.save = function(obj) {
    restService.save(
        {table: "relations", id: obj.id}, obj
    )
}
```

In the service,

```
.service('restService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    var prefixUrl = "http://localhost:4507/v1/rest";
        {
            table: "@table",
            id: "@id"
        },
        {
            query: {
                method: "GET",
            },
            save: {
                method: "PUT",
            },
            delete: {
                method: "DELETE",
            }
        }
    );
}])
```

When I call save, with integer value changed within obj, it's automatically converted to string.

[image: You can see news_count: 0]
[image: You can see news_count: "120"]

You can see news_count: 0 in the first picture, but when I change it's value to 120 and make a request again, $resource seems to change it to "120" instead of 120.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input model changes from Integer to String when changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072152/input-model-changes-from-integer-to-string-when-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Is "obj" binded with ? Value from  should be always string.